# Not able to push to github after npm install --save express

Tags: node.js, express

OK, so I started a project in Node, used npm install to create a package.json file, then pushed to github with no problem.

I then did npm install --save express and got the following error message
fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in      node_modules/express/node_modules/cookie/LICENSE.

Anyone had this issue and knows how to solve it?

Comment: You should put `node_module` in `.gitignore`.

Comment: The error message you are experiencing is related to difference between operating systems concerning line endings. Please read : https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/ 

Additionally, what @SLaks said.

Comment: When I move it to .gitignore, it comes up with the same error message, just related to .gitignore

Comment: this error message comes up after tring to git add . :

Comment: fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in .gitignore/express/node_modules/cookie/LICENSE.